# How do I package javascript files in a portlet application

Tags: javascript, portlet, relative-path

I have written a simple portlet which uses jquery and flot. I need to keep an option open to deploy the portet in a standard portal container such as JBoss, but also to drop into an existing product which uses its own mix of portlets, struts, dojo.

To try and keep my work self-contained I have stored all my js files in a subdirectory relative to my jsp so my  tag looks like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

The relative path is correct, but is not being found in the existing portal container. I suspect that its existing javascript framework, dojo, is setting the base path of the whole application so my relative path spec isn't relative to ".". If I specify an absolute path and move my js files it works.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/AppTopLevel/javascript/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
```

I don't want to do this though as /AppTopLevel will be different when I deploy standalone.

Is there a standard way to package javascript files relative to jsps in a portlet application such that they work in various portal containers and pages written by others which may use conflicting libraries and paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would <%=request.getContextPath()%> help you?